# Drupal Commerce checkout step not submitting

Tags: theming, commerce

I'm trying to overwrite the templates for checkout process on Drupal 7 Commerce.

Here is my template.php of the theme

```
function my_theme_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ) {    
    if ($form_id == 'commerce-checkout-form-checkout') {
    $form['#theme'] = array('commerce_checkout_form_checkout');
    }
}

function my_theme_theme() {
    $items = array();

    $items['commerce_checkout_form_checkout'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'form--checkout-checkout',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme') . '/templates',
    );
```

---

In my form--checkout-checkout.tpl.php i render the form in customized order

```
<?php
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['street_block']['thoroughfare']['#title'] = 'Straße';
    $form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['street_block']['thoroughfare']['#title'] = 'Straße';
    $form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['street_block']['premise']['#title'] = 'Adresszusatz';
    $form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['street_block']['premise']['#title'] = 'Adresszusatz';

    hide($form['cart_contents']);   //Warenkorb
    hide($form['customer_profile_billing']['addressbook']); //Dropdown zur Auswahl der Rechnungsadresse
    hide($form['customer_profile_shipping']['addressbook']);    //Dropdown zur Auswahl der Lieferadresse
    hide($form['commerce_coupon']); //Gutschein
    hide($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality_block']['administrative_area']);
    hide($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality_block']['administrative_area']);
    hide($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_profile_copy']);
    hide($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_profile_copy']);
?>
<div class="form-wrapper checkout-information grid-7 push-3 alpha omega">
    <div class="col-left grid-3 alpha">
        <h2>Rechnungsadresse</h2>
        <?php /* Vorname        */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['name_block']['first_name']); ?>
        <?php /* Nachname       */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['name_block']['last_name']);?>
        <?php /* Firma          */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['organisation_block']['organisation_name']); ?>
        <?php /* Telefon        */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['field_telefon']); ?>
        <?php /* Telefax        */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['field_telefax']); ?>
        <?php /* Straße         */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['street_block']['thoroughfare']); ?>
        <?php /* Adresszusatz   */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['street_block']['premise']); ?>
        <?php /* PLZ            */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality_block']['postal_code']); ?>
        <?php /* Ort            */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality_block']['locality']); ?>
        <?php /* Land           */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_billing']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['country']); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="trennline grid-1">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-right grid-3 omega">
        <h2>Lieferadresse</h2>
        <?php /* Vorname        */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['name_block']['first_name']); ?>
        <?php /* Nachname       */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['name_block']['last_name']);?>
        <?php /* Firma          */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['organisation_block']['organisation_name']); ?>
        <?php /* Telefon        */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['field_telefon']); ?>
        <?php /* Telefax        */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['field_telefax']); ?>
        <?php /* Straße         */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['street_block']['thoroughfare']); ?>
        <?php /* Adresszusatz   */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['street_block']['premise']); ?>
        <?php /* PLZ            */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality_block']['postal_code']); ?>
        <?php /* Ort            */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['locality_block']['locality']); ?>
        <?php /* Land           */  print drupal_render($form['customer_profile_shipping']['commerce_customer_address']['und'][0]['country']); ?>
        <span class="mandatory">*Pflichtfelder</span>
        <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

My problem is, when i click the continue button the page reloads and the form doesn't get submitted.

Comment: I would wonder if it's related to a missing `drupal_render_children($form)` but I see you have included that. Perhaps verify the form elements such as form_id and form_token are present in the themed form.

Comment: yes, both elements get rendered `<input type="hidden" value="form-I7OAroMf4hHoIu8hVImzUukm6jCjFF59qErBxgmrvKI" name="form_build_id">
<input type="hidden" value="ojMsA7d9-VRO-bwObBVsoxuePWBYPyAk8Oe6PkLNgqo" name="form_token">
<input type="hidden" value="commerce_checkout_form_checkout" name="form_id">`

Comment: Not sure what could happen here, but the function (hook) in control of moving/controlling the next step on the checkout is hook_commerce_checkout_router, I'd try to debug the commerce_checkout_commerce_checkout_router implementation of it to see what could be missing.

Comment: I figured out that the pane from the module commerce coupon, which is hided, is causing the problem. I'll try debugging in this way, because the coupon code should be optional.